# Where are default django logging settings?

Tags: python, django, logging

This question has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256919/location-of-django-logs-and-errors/19257221) two years before, however, the answer seems to be incorrect as of at least **django 1.9**.

```
django-admin startproject myproject
cat myproject/settings.py
#no logging related lines, as far as I can tell
```

In django 1.9 [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.9/#default-logging-changes-19) only removal of specific loggers is mentioned.

So, can I see default django logging settings? If so, where?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the documentation for the [`LOGGING`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#logging) setting says, you can see the default logging configuration in `django/utils/log.py`. For example, [here is the config](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/utils/log.py#L17) for Django 3.1.x.

Comment: Thanks for the link to django's documentation on settings ^^

Comment: for me above "LOGGING" link is broken. Try this one - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#logging

Comment: Thanks @KirillOficerov, I've updated the links in the answer