# Extjs with Django CSRF

Tags: ajax, extjs, csrf

I am trying to post a form from Extjs to Django (ver 3.1) as backend
and have an CSRF token Error from the Django side "POST /test/ HTTP/1.1" 403"

My senerio is this :

- My Extjs app run on localhost:1841 (default from extjs for
  development)
- My Django app run on localhost:8000 (defualt Django runserver
  command...)

Both on the same server.

I did read that because I am not generating the form from Django but from
the ExtJS which is external to django ,
I need to get the CSRF through Django api ==> get_token(request)...

so here is my view :

```
def csrf(request):
    return JsonResponse({'csrftoken': get_token(request)})
```

Here is the JS function that call this csrf function...

```
    function getCsrfToken () {
        Ext.Ajax.request ({
            url : 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/csrf/',
    
            success : function (response, opts) {
                obj = Ext.decode (response.responseText, true);
    
#save it for later user...
                Ext.util.Cookies.set('csrftoken', obj['csrftoken']);
                
            },
        })
    };
```

I did test it , and it is working fine by generating CSRF token.

Here is my submit form action (POST) from the ExtJs side...

```
onSubmitClick : function () {
    let form = Ext.getCmp ('formID');
    var csrf = Ext.util.Cookies.get ('csrftoken');
    if (form.isValid ()) 
        form.submit ({
            url : 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/',
            headers : {
                'X-CSRFToken': csrf,
            },

            success : function (form, action) {
                let data = Ext.decode (action.response.responseText)
                Ext.Msg.alert ('Success', data['success']);
            },
            
        });
    } else { // display error alert if the data is invalid
        Ext.Msg.alert ('Invalid Data', 'Please correct form errors.')
    }
}
```

As you can see , I did send the CSRF token from the in the header...

```
headers : {
                    'X-CSRFToken': csrf,
                },
```

After that I did get the Django CSRF Error as shown above.

Here is my Django relevant setting...

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
    
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',

        'DIRS': [
                    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                ],

        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'core.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


# corsheaders
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True


#CSRF
CSRF_HEADER_NAME = 'X-CSRFToken'
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
#CSRF_USE_SESSIONS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
#CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ['127.0.0.1:8000']
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['localhost:1841']
```

Here is the image of the get request for getting the token ...
[image: GET browser log request]

Here is the image log of the Post Request...
[image: POST browser log request]

Any Help With this error please.

Thanks for your replies!

Comment: Have you looked the request in browser`s network (firebug..chrome developer tools), is the CSRFToken sent in header? Have you looked the logs of Django, what they say?

Comment: You may try httpS instead of http..

Comment: Yes , I did , as you can see I updated the post with browser image log.
I did Not tried with https.

Comment: Soooo, Frontend side looks like to be ok. Now you need to check the django logs. Here is some sample on logs configuration, if you have not done it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256919/location-of-django-logs-and-errors/19257221).