# How to include python django's starting message in logging

Tags: python, django, logging

In test, I found out that Python Django application's staring message may contain important warnings, etc, and see the screenshot below for an example. However, the log file didn't include these message.

I'm wondering if there's any setting to include it in logging? Any hints will be highly appreciated.

**Example screen output:**

```
(venv3.7) [user@vnl1916 APPLICATION]$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Performing system checks...

System check identified some issues:

WARNINGS:
eav.Value.value_bool: (fields.W903) NullBooleanField is deprecated. Support for it (except in historical migrations) will be removed in Django 4.0.
        HINT: Use BooleanField(null=True) instead.

System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced).

You have 13 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, authtoken, ebackendapp, sites.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
February 08, 2021 - 12:31:55
Django version 3.1.4, using settings 'ebackendproject.settings'
Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
^C(venv3.7) [user@vnl1916 APPLICATION]$
```

Comment: Have you tried setting up generic Django logging and seeing if these messages are included? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19257221/7942856

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is impossible since the messages go to stdout and some happen before logging is initialized.